# Send Azure Service Bus messages to Blob or Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-servicebus-queues

Can someone let me know if its possible to send Azure Service Bus messages, (Service Bus Queues, in particular) to Azure Data Factory or Blob Storage.

According to the following link, there isn’t a connector for Service Bus with ADF. However, it does state that its possible to send messages to Blob Store. But unfortunately, I can’t find any information on how to send messages to blob storage.

Has anyone come across any links?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/424698/suggest-solution-for-reading-data-from-azure-servi.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to turn Azure Service Bus into a Storage Blob, that's probably easy to achieve. You need a Service Bus trigger to retrieve the message payload and its ID to use as a blob name, storing the payload (message body) using whatever mechanism you want. Could be using Storage SDK to write the contents into a blob. Or a blob output binding with a random blob name. Or the message ID as the blob name. Below is an example of a function that will be triggered by a new message in Service bus queue called `myqueue` and will generate a blob named after message's ID in the `messages` container.

**In-process SDK**

```
public static class MessageTriggeredFunction
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(MessageTriggeredFunction))]
    public static async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string payload,
        string messageId,
        [Blob("messages/{messageId}.txt", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "StorageAccountConnectionString")] Stream output)
    {
        await output.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
    }
}
```

**Isolated worker SDK**

```
public class MessageTriggeredFunctionIsolated
{
   [Function(nameof(MessageTriggeredFunctionIsolated))]
   [BlobOutput("messages/{messageId}.txt", Connection = "StorageAccountConnectionString")]
   public string Run(
       [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string payload,
       string messageId)
  {
            return payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for reaching out. I got to be honest I don't entirely understand what your code is attempting to achieve? I'm not sure what you mean where you mention turning Azure Service Bus into Storage Blob. My objective is send Service Bus messages to an Azure blob store.

Comment: I've updated the code below for you to copy and try locally. It does exactly what you've asked about. Note that the connection strings are names of the kyes in the settings (`local.appsettings.json`) and not the actual connection strings.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks again for reaching out, and with the update. As I'm very new to writing code, can you just give me a dummies guide on how to apply this code. Sorry for being such a newbie

Comment: No worries. I'd recommend reading up on [Azure Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). Specifically, you want to learn about triggers and output bindings. The sample code is using [Service Bus trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) and [Storage Blob output binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob). A good starting point would be the [samples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?products=azure-functions&languages=csharp)