# What are common strategies to ingest messages from a service bus topic into Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, servicebus, data-ingestion

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have an Azure Service Bus topic that stores events, and I want to store these events (topic messages) into Azure Data Explorer for further analysis and querying. I currently have a downstream consumer that subscribes to the Service Bus topic and processes these events.

I would like to explore the common strategies or approaches to ingest these messages from the Azure Service Bus topic into Azure Data Explorer. Specifically, I am seeking guidance on the following:

What are the recommended methods for extracting and transferring messages from the Azure Service Bus topic to Azure Data Explorer?
Are there any Azure native services or connectors that simplify this ingestion process?
How can I ensure reliable and efficient data ingestion from the Service Bus topic to Azure Data Explorer?
Are there any best practices or considerations regarding data schema, partitioning, or indexing in Azure Data Explorer for this scenario?
Are there any performance or scalability considerations when dealing with high volumes of messages?
I have done some initial research, but I would appreciate insights and guidance from the community based on real-world experiences and best practices.

Thank you for your assistance!

I have explored the Azure Data Explorer documentation and the Azure Service Bus documentation to understand the individual services. I also looked for relevant tutorials or guides, but I couldn't find specific examples or best practices for ingesting messages from Azure Service Bus topic into Azure Data Explorer.

Putting the pieces of what I found so far, it seems there are two general approaches I can explore:

1. Service Bus topic -> Event Grid (separate subscription) -> Azure Web Function -> ADX
2. Service Bus topic -> Event Hub -> ADX

As there is no guide which covers this specific use case, I'd appreciate any feedback on the direction I'm researching.

Answer (score 0):

you could try having the messages written as blobs, then use an EventGrid data connection to automatically ingest the results blobs to your target database/table.

2 options for doing so:

- Power Automate template:

  - https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/276c5a70ecb74b5da33ee7c02f1a5678/create-azure-blobs-from-azure-queue-messages/
- Service bus trigger:

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71262305/7861807